# SQL Server: Is there a way to select alias column from aggregate function?

Tags: sql, function, aggregate, alias

So I have these columns from performing an aggregate function:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQcwF.png)

```
SELECT MachineName,

       (100*((1)
       -((
       sum(CASE p1.CounterName
             WHEN 'Available Bytes' THEN
               p2.CounterValue
             ELSE
               0
           END)
       /NULLIF(
       (sum(CASE p1.CounterName
              WHEN 'Available Bytes' THEN
                p2.CounterValue
              ELSE
                0
            END)
        +
        sum(CASE p1.CounterName
              WHEN 'Committed Bytes' THEN
                p2.CounterValue
              ELSE
                0
            END)
        +
        sum(CASE p1.CounterName
              WHEN 'Modified Page List Bytes' THEN
                p2.CounterValue
              ELSE
                0
            END)),0) ))))  As Memory
```

I only want Memory > 75 that needs to be selected but I'm not familiar enough with SQL and aggregate function so I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using subquery like below -

```
select * from 
(
SELECT MachineName,

       (100*((1)
       -((
       sum(CASE p1.CounterName
             WHEN 'Available Bytes' THEN
               p2.CounterValue
             ELSE
               0
           END)
       /NULLIF(
       (sum(CASE p1.CounterName
              WHEN 'Available Bytes' THEN
                p2.CounterValue
              ELSE
                0
            END)
        +
        sum(CASE p1.CounterName
              WHEN 'Committed Bytes' THEN
                p2.CounterValue
              ELSE
                0
            END)
        +
        sum(CASE p1.CounterName
              WHEN 'Modified Page List Bytes' THEN
                p2.CounterValue
              ELSE
                0
            END)),0) ))))  As Memory
)A where memory>75
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. But I have a follow up question, what if I also want to select the MachineName that occurs 5 times. I've tried doing  Where Memory >75 and Having Count(MachineName)> 0 but it doesn't work. I think it doesn't work because MachienName is a varchar but I also don't want to list out all of the Machine Name and do it this way: Where Memory > 75 and count(Machine Name = 'Machine 1') > 5 because I have 30+ machine names under MachineName column.

Comment: @123testing123, it would be better if you post another question

Comment: Okay will do. Thank you. :)